# How to get/clear dynamicly nested UserControls in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, user-controls, instance

I am looking for a way to nest-, get-, clear- & define usercontrols (UC).
I'd love if you have any links to really good descriptions or tutorials to the following Problems.

First off, all two little pictures for a better understanding of the Project.
& sorry for the bad grammar and especially for writing Category wrong.

[image: Scamattic]

[image: The application running and populated]

Hope that the images make it clear, that I'd like a window, where I can add a Category UC that can be extended as much as one wants. In each of the Categories you are also able to add infinite control UCs.

I am able to populate the windows how I want with the code below, but I'm missing a way to call each UC individually.

I'm looking for:

- If the identification of a UC by naming it, is valid /the best way
- A way to call each UC individually
- clear a specific UC
- And all other Tips you are willing to give ;)

I think the answers are really obvious but i just dont know, what i am looking for.

Thanks upfront for every answer :)

The Code:

The Main Window CS

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn_Activate_UCKategory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UC_Kategory UC = new UC_Kategory();

        //UC.Name = "Some Unique Name... Probably the Kategory name (will be saved in json)...  Same goes for Content";
        // How to best refer to a instance of Kategory or Content? Over Name?

        UC.UC_Kategory_Header.Text = UC_Main_txt_Kategory.Text;
        UC_Main_txt_Kategory.Text = "Write Here";
        UCKategory_Wrapper.Children.Add(UC);
    }
}
```

The Category UC CS

```csharp
public partial class UC_Kategory : UserControl
{
    public UC_Kategory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn_Delete_UCKategory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // How to Clear a specific Kategory
        MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        mainWindow.UCKategory_Wrapper.Children.Clear(); // Can only clear all Kategory UCs...
    }
    private void btn_Create_UCContent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UC_Content UC = new UC_Content();
        UC.UC_Content_Header.Text = UC_Kategory_txt_Kategory.Text;
        UC_Kategory_txt_Kategory.Text = "Write Here";
        UCContent_StackPanel.Children.Add(UC);
    }
}
```

The Main Window xaml

```xml
<Grid Margin="10">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Name of Kategory: " Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox Text="Write here" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="UC_Main_txt_Kategory"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_Create_UCKategory" Content="Create Kategory" Grid.Column="2" Click="btn_Activate_UCKategory_Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <WrapPanel x:Name="UCKategory_Wrapper"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is too broad, but for start you may want to use ItemsControl instead of concrete panels such as Grid or WrapPanels. the next thing you want to do is to use MVVM pattern to populate your controls and AVOID events and x:Name completely.

Comment: You shouldn't use `StackPanel` with manual fill. Use `ItemsControl` with `Binding` to collection like `ObservableCollection<T>`, also you may set `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` as `WrapPanel`. Then clearing the collection will remove all the visuals from UI.

Comment: Big thanks to you two, read a little into it and it seems like the way to go for me.